# Extracting BCI Geodetic and ECI coordinates of an orbit

Tags: astropy, orbital-mechanics

I am using astropy to define a Tundra orbit around Earth and subsequently, I would like to extract the ECI and geodetic coordinates as the object propagates in time. I was able to get something but it does not agree with what I would expect (ECI coordinates extracted from another SW). The two orbits are not even on the same plane, which is clearly wrong.

Can anybody tell me if I am doing something obviously wrong?

The plot below shows the two results. Orange is with Astropy.

[image: Orbit Comparison]

```
import astropy
from astropy import units as u
from poliastro.bodies import Earth
from astropy.coordinates import CartesianRepresentation
from poliastro.twobody import Orbit
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

epoch = astropy.time.Time('2020-01-01T00:00:00.000',  scale='tt')

# Tundra
tundra1 = Orbit.from_classical(attractor=Earth,
    a = 42164 *u.km,
    ecc = 0.2684 * u.one,
    inc = 63.4 * u.deg,
    raan = 25 * u.deg,
    argp = 270 * u.deg,
    nu = 50 * u.deg,
    # epoch=epoch
)

def plot_orb(orb, start_t, end_t, step_t, ax, c='k'):
    orb_list = []
    for t in np.arange(start_t, end_t, step_t):
        single_orb = orb.propagate(t*u.min)
        orb_list = orb_list + [single_orb]

    xyz = orb.sample().xyz

    ax.plot(*xyz,'r')
    s_xyz_ar = np.zeros((len(orb_list), 3))
    for i, s_orb in enumerate(orb_list):
        s_xyz = s_orb.represent_as(CartesianRepresentation).xyz
        s_xyz_ar[i, :] = s_xyz
    ax.scatter(s_xyz_ar[:, 0], s_xyz_ar[:, 1], s_xyz_ar[:, 2], c)

    return s_xyz_ar, t

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

s_xyz_ar1, t1 = plot_orb(orb=tundra1, start_t=0, end_t=1440, step_t=10, ax=ax, c='k')
```

Comment: Can you please post the results you did get and explain a bit more about what you were expecting?  I just ran your code with astropy 4.0 and poliastro 0.14.0 and got the result I think you were expecting, with the points of the scatter plot perfectly following the red orbit path.  There are also some things in your code that are pretty inefficient, but we can address that later.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.... I added an image of the two orbits. I would expect both of them to be identical, but as you can see they are not even on the same plane. I am new to astropy so I am clearly doing something wrong. And yes I know my code is very inefficient, especially the way I propagate the orbit in time, but that was the only way I have found so far to do that. Any suggestions would be more than welcome. 
With regards to poliastro, I tried using that first, but I could not find a way to propagate the orbit to a specific time offset. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: It turns out the difference was due to a different epoch assumed by the two SW. Once this was fixed, everything matches. But I would be very interested in knowing how to make the code run more efficiently and getting rid of the for-loop

Comment: I see, I think I hadn't understood your question properly.  In that case I was not able to reproduce it.  I didn't understand what you meant previously by "ECI coordinates extracted from another SW" in which case it would be important to know what was done differently with that software.

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote that you can do this more efficiently I was under the mistaken assumption that `Orbit.propagate` can be called directly on an array of time steps like:

```py
>>> tt = np.arange(0, 1440, 10) * u.min
>>> orb = tundra1.propagate(tt)
```

While this "works" in that it returns a new orbit with an array of epochs, it appears `Orbit` is not really designed to work with an array of epochs and trying to do something like `orb.represent_as` just returns a value for the first epoch in the array.  This would be a nice possible enhancement to poliastro.

However, the code you wrote for the scatter plot can still be significantly simplified to something like this:

```
>>> tt = np.arange(0, 1440, 10) * u.min
>>> xyz = np.vstack([tundra1.propagate(t).represent_as(CartesianRepresentation).xyz for t in tt])
>>> fig = plt.figure()
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
>>> ax.scatter(*xyz.T)
>>> fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Ideally you should be able to do this without the `np.vstack` and instead just call `tundra1.propagate(tt).represent_as(CartesianRepresentation).xyz` without a for loop.  But as the above demonstrates you can still simplify a lot by using `np.vstack` to make an array from a list of `(x, y, z)` triplets.

I'm not sure this really answers your original question though, which it seems you found the answer to that wasn't really related to the code.  Still, I hope this helps!